# InvalidOperationException After installing Visual Studio 11 Beta

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I recently installed Visual Studio 11 Beta with .Net Framework 4.5 on mine production machine (but left Visual Studio 2010 side-by-side). It worked fine for me for couple of days, but then it started throwing `InvalidOperationException` in this section of code:

```
ItemDB itemDB = new ItemDB();
ItemDetails item = itemDB.GetItem((int)Session["itemId"]);
string code = item.Code;
Control html = ParseControl(code);
placeholderPage.Controls.Add(html);
```

Exception happens on line where I `ParseControl`, in string code I have regular html. The strangest thing is that this code worked perfectly before I installed new Visual Studio, and it still works on colleges machine where he has VS2010 on .NET Framework 4.

After exception it shows me this message: `Cannot instantiate type 'TracedLiteralControl' because there is no public parameterless constructor.`

Comment: It is .NETs method with signature `public Control ParseControl(string content)`, i did not wrote it...

Comment: .NET 4.5 overwrites .NET 4.0, not side-by-side.  Avoid installing betas on production machines.

Comment: Hm, but i set build target to .NET 4. Does that make difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same annoying problem, but when using Page.ParseControl.
Here are details:
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
Message: Cannot instantiate type 'TracedLiteralControl' because there is no public parameterless constructor.

Then looking at the CallStack I found the following interesting line:
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Runtime.WebForms.TracedLiteralControlBuilder.BuildObject() + 0x2f bytes

Looks like, for the purpose of new PageInspector feature, VS 11 plugs an assembly in my web app runtime. I didn't for sure added that assembly, so the obvious place to look for was in the .NET Framework configuration and in particular in web.config

In my case the file is placed under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config and "Bingo" - on line 88 I found next:

```
<add assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

I commented out the line and my apps are working fine again.

Hope that helps,
Velio

Comment: I ended up uninstalling VS11, I will wait for final version... Thx anyway.

Comment: I think, even not 100% sure, problems for me started when I tested PageInspector. Before that everything worked fine long time after I have isntalled VS 11 beta.

Comment: Giving a +1 here because this solution worked for me. Good one, thanks.

Comment: Had problems with Visual Studio freezing when debugging a web project, when it was loading the PageInspector dll. Commenting it out according to your instructions helped, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have problems with the Page Inspector, you can disable it in your own web.config:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <remove assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: Got the problem after installing VS2013 and then running an old solution in VS2010. Your solution worked, thank you!